# How to integrate payment in React-Native using "Authorize.net"?

Tags: react-native, payment-gateway, authorize.net

Now I am developing an Ecommerce app and website with React-Native and ReactJS.
And I am gonna integrate payment option by using `Accept.js` of `Authorize.net`.
I integrated successfully in website(ReactJS) using `authorizenet` package.

> Can I use this package in React-Native mobile app also?

> If this package is not available to use in mobile app, should I use web-view in RN app?

> Or what package should I use for payment integration in react-native app?
> (Paypal and Stripe is not acceptable in this app because of PCI compliant.)

Comment: have you got any answer for this?